# How do I evaluate $\oint_{|z|=1} \frac1{z^2 \sin z} dz$ by means of the Cauchy residue theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate the integral by means of the Cauchy residue theorem.

$$\oint_{|z|=1} \dfrac{1}{z^{2} \sin z} dz$$.

So Cauchy's Residue Theorem states:

> If $\Gamma$ is a simple closed positively oriented contour and $f$ is analytic inside and on $\Gamma$ except at the points $z_{1},z_{2},...,z_{n}$ inside $\Gamma$, then
>
> $$\int_{\Gamma} f(z)dz = 2\pi i \sum_{j=1}^{n} Res (z_{j})$$

where Res denotes the residue of $f$ at $z_{0}$. I thought that I could go about this problem by letting $f= \dfrac{1/ \sin z}{(z-0)^{2}}$ and then taking the derivative of $\dfrac{1}{ \sin z}$ at $z_0=0$ to get the residue of $f$ at $0$, but then I get that the residue of $f$ at $0$ is $1$, and then using Cauchy's Residue Theorem, I get that

$$\oint_{|z|=1} \dfrac{1}{z^{2} \sin z} dz = 2\pi i$$

which is different from the answer in the book. I'd like to know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: why should taking the derivative of $\frac{1}{\sin z}$ at 0 give the residue of $f$ at 0? For example, $1/z$ has residue 1 at 0 by definition, but the derivative of the constant 1 at 0 is 0

Comment: You seem to be assuming you have a simple pole. But it's a triple pole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=0$. Expanding as a Laurent series gives
$$f(z)=z^{-2}\left(z-\frac{z^3}6+\cdots\right)^{-1}
=z^{-3}\left(1-\frac{z^2}6+\cdots\right)^{-1}
=z^{-3}\left(1+\frac{z^2}6+\cdots\right)
=z^{-3}+\frac{1}{6z}+\cdots$$
giving the residue as $1/6$. Therefore the integral is $\pi i/3$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $$\lim_{z \to 0} z^3\frac{1}{z^2 \sin z}=\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z}{ \sin z} \neq 0$$ but  $$\lim_{z \to 0} z^4\frac{1}{z^2 \sin z}=\lim_{z \to 0}z\left(\frac{z}{\sin z}\right)=0$$ so $0$ is  pole of order $3$.

Thus $$\text{Res}\{f(z):0\}=\frac{1}{2!} \frac{d^2}{dz^2}[z^3f(z)]\bigg|_{z=0}=\frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2}{dz^2}\left[\frac{z}{\sin z}\right]\Bigg|_{z=0}\\=\frac{1}{2}\Big[z \left(\csc ^3{z}+\cot ^2{z} \csc{z}\right)-2 \cot{z} \csc\Big]\Bigg|_{z=0}=\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{3}$$

So $$\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z^2 \sin z}dz=2\pi i \cdot \frac{1}{6}=\frac{\pi i}{3}$$